# The $QC$ functions described by Sarason.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I'm reading one of the articles written by Sarason. He define the space $QC$ as the  $C^*$algebra generated by $H^{\infty} + C$, that is, $QC=(H^{\infty} + C) \cap (\bar{H}^{\infty} + C)$. I'm using the fact that $QC\neq C$ but  i need an explicit example of this. All that I have is this: if $f$ is a conformal maping between the unit disk and a "suitable" domain, then, the boundary function is in $QC$. Another possibility is to find a continuous real value function $u$ such that its conjugate $v$ (the function $v$ such that $u+iv$ is analytic) is discontinuous at one point.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this from, in which article?

Comment: @JonasMeyer First one was [Algebras of functions on the unit circle](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183534432), followed by [Functions of vanishing mean oscillation](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-207-00/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3/home.html) which introduced a better known function space.

Answer (score 1):

> Another possibility is to find a continuous real value function $u$ such that its conjugate $v$  is discontinuous at one point.

That would not be enough, since discontinuity does not rule out membership in $H^\infty$. What you need is an example of a continuous function for which the conjugate is unbounded at a particular boundary point. I gave such an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910456/): it's based on a conformal map onto a domain with thin infinite tail, like $0<y<1/(1+x^2)$.